# Windows Driver - Read CPU Temperature - Dual core

Tags: windows, driver, cpu, temperature

I need to read the CPU temperature of an Intel x86_64 processor. For that I am planning to write a Windows kernel mode driver that can make use of the call __readdmsr 'asm' command.

But I am not sure on how to select the core for which the readmsr command is to be applied.

Can you please help me with this?

Comment: Is there some reason you can't just use WBEM to read it from user mode?  There's an example at https://gist.github.com/jeffa00/9577816 that uses powershell, but there are lots of examples of how to read WBEM data from various languages.

Comment: @DavidWohlferd We already have a driver for getting CPU temperature and what we need is just switching between cores.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you could use [`KeSetSystemAffinityThread`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff553267%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for that. Restrict the thread with 'rdmsr` to the processor you want to check.